# How to forward a WOL package upstream?

Tags: networking, wake-on-lan

I know how to use `wakeonlan` with `-i <IP>` to wake a device that is located in a different LAN.

But somehow it will not work in a certain  - "upstream" - direction:

When I am on a device in `192.168.178.0/24` and the router (a TD-W8970B) is the gateway on `192.168.178.1` that is connected to `192.168.200.0/24` on it's `WAN` port, the package will not be forwarded "upstream" so to speak.

Is there a special setting for routers to allow this kind of traffic over them?

I don't mean opening a port on the `WAN` from outside - I want to do it the other way around!

---

EDIT: There is a firewall on the TP-Link, but it is deactivated. Maybe the problem could be with the gateway on the "above" LAN `192.168.200.0/24`.

Comment: a sleeping device doesn't answer ARP. Without ARP requests available the last hop system must either know the target MAC address in its network configuration or do a broadcast instead. In both cases, special support on the router is needed. Hope this will nudge you in the right direction. As the issue is on the router, if the router isn't a router with standard  Unix/Linux commands, I'm not sure Unix/Linux SE is the best place to ask.

Comment: Maybe the problem is the ISPs standard router in the target LAN that is not able to does this. I configured a static IP for this MAC on this router, so the data should be available if the device is sleeping.

Comment: The very last equipment matters (last hop router). Not equipments before.

Comment: It depends on how to understand the WOL request. Does it query the gateway of the target LAN to send the request? Or does the router between those two LANs send the request on it's WAN port directly into the target LAN. Since he knows that this is the right LAN it would suffice to broadcast to it (maybe).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN#Magic_packet (see also "subnet directed broadcasts" which [defaults to "no"](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2644#section-3))

Comment: I found that the right command actually DOES forward my WOL package from one LAN into a wireguard tunnel and then does broadcast a MAC into the destination LAN. I just did use a tool wrong. However, I still wonder why `wakeonlan -i <IP> <MAC>` does forward the package from LAN1 into wireguard tunnel (LAN2) and out of the tunnel into LAN3, but stops there instead of using the final route to LAN4 over the TP-Link Router.